Prove $f$ is uniformly continuous, iff for any infinitesimal $\{a_n\}$, the sequence $\{f(x-a_n)\}$ is uniformly convergent to $f$
I'm tring to prove $f$ is uniformly continuous, iff for any infinitesimal $\{a_n\}$, the sequence $\{f(x-a_n)\}$ is uniformly convergent to $f$.

I managed to prove the necessity:
Assume $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$, then$$
\def\abs#1{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
\let\epsilon\varepsilon
(\forall\epsilon>0)
(\exists\delta>0)
(\forall x_1,x_2 \in D)
[\abs{x_1-x_2}<\delta
\implies
\abs{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}<\epsilon].
$$
Assume a sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, then$$
(\forall\delta>0)
(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})
(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})
[n>N \implies \abs{a_n}<\delta],
$$
Hence,$$
(\forall\epsilon>0)
(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})
(\forall n>N)
(\forall x \in D)
[\abs{f(x)-f(x-a_n)}<\epsilon],
$$
that is, $\{f(x-a_n)\}$ converges uniformly on $D$.

However, I have no idea how to compose the proof for sufficiency.
Could you please enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

suppose for the sake of contradiction that $f$ is not uniformly continuous. then by definition there is some $\varepsilon_0 >0$ such that for all $\delta >0$  there are $x, y \in D $ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge \varepsilon_0$. In particular, there are sequances {$x_n$}, {$y_n$} $\subset D$ such that $|x_n-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \ge \varepsilon_0$. define $a_n = y_n - x_n$. by the squeeze theorem $a_n \to 0$, but by uniform convergence you get that there exist some $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|f(y_n-a_n)-f(y_n)|<\varepsilon_0$, meaning $\varepsilon_0 \le |f(x_n)-f(y_n)| = |f(y_n-a_n)-f(y_n)| <\varepsilon_0$. contradiction

You forgot to mention what $D$ it is.
If not argue by contradiction, then maybe we can turn to the following characterization:
$$
f: D \to \mathbb R \text{ is uniformly continuous on }D \iff F(\delta):= \sup_{\substack {x,y \in D \\ |x - y| < \delta} } |f(x) - f(y)|\xrightarrow {\delta \to 0^+} 0. 
$$
And similarly, a sequence $f_n : D \to \Bbb R$ of functions converges uniformly to a function $f : D \to \Bbb R$ if and only if the sequence $$
\beta_n := \sup_{x \in D}|f_n(x) - f(x)| \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0. 
$$
Then the proof can go as follows: it is equivalent to prove for any sequence of nonnegative numbers $\delta_n \to 0$, that $F(\delta_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. By definition of $\sup$, we can find $x_n, y_n \in D$  for each natural number $n$ such that $|x_n - y_n| < \delta_n$ and
$$
F(\delta_n  ) - \frac 1n \leqslant |f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \leqslant F(\delta_n).  
$$
Let $a_n := x_n - y_n$, then it is a sequence converging to $0$ since $|a_n| < \delta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. By assumption, $f(x - a_n) \rightrightarrows f(x)$ on $D$. Then by definition of $\sup$ (again),
\begin{align*}
F(\delta_n) &\leqslant |f(x_n) - f(x_n - a_n)| + \frac 1n \\
& \leqslant \frac 1n + \sup_{x\in D} |f(x) - f(x-a_n)| \\
&\longrightarrow 0 \quad {}[n \to \infty]. 
\end{align*}
Then the statement is proved.
